# Show that if $\Omega_1,\Omega_2$ are tangent vectors of curves in $SO(3)$ then $[\Omega_1,\Omega_2]\in\mathfrak{so}(3)$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $so(3)$ be the Lie Algebra of $SO(3)$ and $R\in SO(3); \Omega_1,\Omega_2 \in so(3)$ and $\Omega_n = \frac{d}{dt}R_n(t)$ at the point $t=0$. So $\Omega_n$ is the tangent vector of the curve $R_n(t)$ at $t=0$.

To show that the Lie bracket $[\Omega_1,\Omega_2]$ is an element of $so(3)$ my professor wrote:

$$
\tag{1}[\Omega_1,\Omega_2] = \left.\frac{d}{dt}R_1(t)\Omega_2 R_1(t)^{-1}\right|_{t=0}
$$

I am trying to understand that, but I cannot see why this shows that the commutator is an element of $so(3)$.

I understand that for this tangential vector to be in $so(3)$, the product $R_1(t)\Omega_2 R_1(t)^{-1}$ has to be a parametrized curve in $SO(3)$.

But I do not see why it is a curve in $SO(3)$.

Comment: I want to be clear about what you are asking :) Do you want to know why the product $R_1(t)\Omega_2R_1(t)^{-1}$ "has to be a parametrized curve" living completely with $SO(3)$.  Or, are you asking if it is a parametrized curve" living completely with $SO(3)$, then you can using it in the above formula to calculate $[\Omega_1, \Omega_2]$.

Comment: I want to see the proof that the Lie bracket $[\Omega_1,\Omega_2]$ is an element of $so(3)$. In other words, this is the proof that the tangent space of $SO(3)$ at the unity matrix is a Lie algebra, if you use the commutator as the Lie bracket. My professor wrote the above formula $(1)$ as proof, but I don't understand it.

Comment: Edited question for clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We want to show that
$$
\tag{1}[\Omega_1,\Omega_2] = \left.\frac{d}{dt}R_1(t)\Omega_2 R_1(t)^{-1}\right|_{t=0}
$$

We can start doing this by computing:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left.\frac{d}{dt}\left(R_1(t)\Omega_2 R_1(t)^{-1}\right)\right|_{t=0} &=&
\left.\left[\frac{d}{dt}R_1(t)(\Omega_2 R_1(t)^{-1})\right]\right|_{t=0} + \left.\left[(R_1(t)\Omega_2) \frac{d}{dt}R_1(t)^{-1}\right]\right|_{t=0} \\
&=&
\left[\Omega_1\Omega_2 R_1(0)^{-1}\right] + \left.\left[R_1(t)\Omega_2 \frac{d}{dt}R_1(t)^{-1}\right]\right|_{t=0} \\
&=&
\left[\Omega_1\Omega_2 R_1(0)^{-1}\right] + \left.\left[R_1(t)\Omega_2 (-R_1(t)^{-1})\left(\frac{d}{dt}R_1(t)\right)R_1(t)^{-1})\right]\right|_{t=0} \\
&=&
\left[\Omega_1\Omega_2 R_1(0)^{-1}\right] - \left.\left[R_1(t)\Omega_2 R_1(t)^{-1}\left(\frac{d}{dt}R_1(t)\right)R_1(t)^{-1})\right]\right|_{t=0} \\
&=&
\left[\Omega_1\Omega_2 R_1(0)^{-1}\right] - \left[R_1(0)\Omega_2 R_1(0)^{-1}\left.\left(\frac{d}{dt}R_1(t)\right|_{t=0}\right)R_1(0)^{-1})\right] \\
&=&
\left[\Omega_1\Omega_2 R_1(0)^{-1}\right] - \left[R_1(0)\Omega_2 R_1(0)^{-1}\Omega_1R_1(0)^{-1})\right] \\
\end{eqnarray*}

See [Derivatives of Inverse Matrix](http://planetmath.org/derivativeofinversematrix) for details on the third line's derivation.

There isn't much further we can go without knowing more details about $R_1$.  I actually think it might have been defined as
$$R_i(t) = e^{\Omega_it}$$
But it's only necessary to require $R_i(0) = I$.  Then the final line above gives $\Omega_1\Omega_2 - \Omega_2\Omega_1$.

---

Update to include additional requirements:

> The curve is in $SO(3)$

This is not always true.  A Lie group is a subgroup of $GL$ but a Lie algebra always contains the $0$ matrix.  It maps to the identity of the Lie group.  So if $\Omega_2 = 0$ in the above, then the curve $C(t) = 0$ does not lie in $SO(3)$.

> Show $[\Omega_1, \Omega_2]$ is in $\mathfrak{so}(3)$

This is true independently of the above considerations.  $\Omega_1, \Omega_2$ are elements of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ which is closed under addition and multiplication (matrices of the form $X^T = -X$).

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't express myself clearly. I see that formula (1) is correct, you showed it using the "product rule of differentiation". However, for $[\Omega_1,\Omega_2]$ to be an element of $so(3)$, this is not sufficient. You also need to show that $C(t) = R_1(t)\Omega_2 R_1(t)^{-1}$ is a curve in $SO(3)$ with $C(0)=\mathbb{1}$.

Comment: @BastianTreichler - Updated

Comment: Thanks, but your last remark is not true. $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ is not closed under multiplication: $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0\\-1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\-1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\\0 & -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ The Lie bracket **IS** the multiplication in $\mathfrak{so}(3)$, and this does not seem trivial.

Comment: @BastianTreichler - Yes, by "multiplication", I meant the one for the lie-algebra, namely the bracket.  What I am saying is $[\Omega_1, \Omega_2] = \Omega_1\Omega_2 - \Omega_2\Omega_1$ is part of the definition of the Lie Algebra.

Comment: Well but that's what I want to see proved. **WHY** is $SO(3)$ with the commutator a Lie algebra. Just by saying that it's part of the definition does not prove that it applies to $SO(3)$.

Comment: @BastianTreichler   hmm, well once you obtain the formula from the above that $\Omega_1\Omega_2 - \Omega_2\Omega_1$ is the commutator, you can show it is an element of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ as follows.  Elements of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ are those matrices that satisfy $X^T = -X$.  Then $[X, Y]^T = (XY - YX)^T = Y^TX^T - X^TY^T = -[X^T, Y^T] = -[(-X), (-Y)] = -[X, Y]$.

Comment: Thanks, now I'm happy :) still wondering what my professor wanted to do with that formula (1).

Comment: @BastianTreichler - your final statement left me wondering as well.  I added another answer to the thread.

Answer (score 2):

Formula (1) is a bit strange indeed, $R_1(t)\Omega_2 R_1(t)^{-1}$ is not necessarily in $SO(3)$ ($\Omega_2$ could have a null determinant for example).

One way to prove the result, is to consider that (for $t \to 0$):

$$ R_1(t) = I + t \Omega_1 + t^2 W_1 + o(t^2)$$
$$ R_2(t) = I + t \Omega_2 + t^2 W_2 + o(t^2)$$

Then:

$$ R_1(t)R_2(t) = I + t (\Omega_1 + \Omega_2) + t^2 (W_1 + W_2 + \Omega_1 \Omega_2) + o(t^2)$$
$$ R_2(t)R_1(t) = I + t (\Omega_1 + \Omega_2) + t^2 (W_1 + W_2 + \Omega_2 \Omega_1) + o(t^2)$$

The you can consider $L(t) = R_1(t)^{-1}R_2(t)^{-1}R_1(t)R_2(t)$ which is a curve in $SO(3)$. Since $R_2(t)R_1(t)L(t) = R_1(t)R_2(t)$, you can develop term by term each side and find that:

$$ L(t) = I + t^2([\Omega_1, \Omega_2]) + o(t^2)$$

If you re-parametrise L with $s = t^2$ you have $L(s) = I + s([\Omega_1, \Omega_2]) + o(s)$ Thus you have found a curve in $SO(3)$ whose tangent is $[\Omega_1, \Omega_2]$.

Comment: Thanks, but the last term $L(s)=I+s([\Omega_1,\Omega_2])+O(s)$ still contains that $O(s)$ term. What if that term was $sM+O(s^2)$ with some matrix $M$. Then the tangent of $L(s)$ is $M+[\Omega_1,\Omega_2]$, which is different from $[\Omega_1,\Omega_2]$.

Comment: Why is $R_2(t)^{-1}R_1(t)^{-1}L(t) = R_1(t)R_2(t)$ ? I think the inversions are wrong, but you didn't accept my edit.

Comment: @BastianTreichler: Thanks for the remark. My $O(.)$ are indeed $o(.)$, this was a typo. I edited it.

Comment: @cheeesus: I think the way wrote is correct. If $L(t) = R_1(t)^{-1}R_2(t)^{-1}R_1(t)R_2(t)$ then you need to multiply from the left by $R_1(t)$ and then by $R_2(t)$ to obtain the second expression.

Comment: Exactly, but you are left-multiplying by $R_1(t)^{-1}$ and then by $R_2(t)^{-1}$.

Comment: @Tantto: Isn't $o(.)$ a stronger condition than $O(.)$? At least Wikipedia says so: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution, but it has nothing to do with $(1)$:

$$
\begin{align}
[\Omega_1,\Omega_2] & = \Omega_1\Omega_2-\Omega_2\Omega_1 = (-\Omega_1^T)(-\Omega_2^T) - (-\Omega_2^T)(-\Omega_1^T) \\ & = \Omega_1^T\Omega_2^T-\Omega_2^T\Omega_1^T=(\Omega_2\Omega_1)^T-(\Omega_1\Omega_2)^T = (\Omega_2\Omega_1-\Omega_1\Omega_2)^T \\ & = -[\Omega_2,\Omega_1]
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possibility as to how the professor was arriving at the result that $[\Omega_1, \Omega_2]$ is an element of the Lie algebra.  Suppose that we take the above formula as the definition of the Lie Bracket:
$$
\tag{1}[\Omega_1,\Omega_2] = \left.\frac{d}{dt}R_1(t)\Omega_2 R_1(t)^{-1}\right|_{t=0}
$$
There is a proposition that for any Lie group element $A$ and Lie algebra element $X$ (of its associated Lie algebra), that $AXA^{-1}$ is also in the Lie algebra.  (Proof from Hall: $e^{t(AXA^{-1})} = Ae^{tX}A^{-1}$ and the latter is in the Lie group).

This means in the above, the curve $$C(t) = R_1(t)\Omega_2 R_1(t)^{-1}$$
lies entirely in the Lie algebra.  Hence its derivative at $t = 0$ is also in the Lie algebra (because a Lie algebra is a vector space).  So the misconception from the original question was that $C(t)$ lives in $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ instead of $SO(3)$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more about the *Proof from Hall* part? If you read my question, this was exactly the thing I wanted to see. I can't yet see why $C(t)$ must be a curve in $SO(3)$.

Comment: What misconception do you mean? I never asked why $C(t)$ is in $so(3)$. My original question was: why is $C(t) \in SO(3)$ for an interval around $t=0$.

Comment: It is not a curve in $SO(3)$ it is a curve in $\mathfrak{so}(3)$.  Regarding the proof, the RHS is an element of the group because it is the product of three group elements.  Then by definition of the Lie Algebra, if $e^{t(AXA^{-1}}$ in the Lie group for all $t$, then $AXA^{-1}$ is in the Lie algebra.

Comment: Yes, what I am saying is that is where you went wrong.

Comment: Oh now I see... I always expected $C(t)$ to be in $SO(3)$ so that $(1)$ defines a tangential vector and thus a member of $so(3)$. Okay, so now that this is sorted out, do you have more information about that "Proof of Hall"? When I google it, I only find pages about Hall's theorem, which is something else.

Comment: @BastianTreichler - Great book: Hall - "Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations"

Comment: So it's too non-trivial for an MSE answer?