# Prove that the commutator is a Lie bracket in $\mathrm{Lie}(G)$

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a matrix Lie group (i.e. a closed subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb C)$), and consider the set (following the notation in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group%E2%80%93Lie_algebra_correspondence)):
$$\mathrm{Lie}(G)\equiv\{X\in M(n,\mathbb C) : \,\,e^{tX}\in G\,\,\forall t\in\mathbb R\}.$$
I know that this turns out to be a Lie algebra [with Lie bracket given by the commutator of matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/460079/173147), but I'm trying to get a better understanding of why this is the case.

The case $G=SO(3)$, $\mathfrak g=\mathfrak{so}(3)$ was worked out in [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1393577/173147). What about the more general scenario of $G$ an arbitrary closed subset of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb C)$? Can a similar argument be made in this case?

Comment: I think Theorem 3.20 in Brian C Hall's [*Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations*](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319134666) answers your question.

Comment: can you recommend an online freely available resource?

Comment: There's an arXiv file by the same author. See Theorem 3.16 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0005032).

Answer (score 1):

We need to check that ${\rm Lie}(G)$ is (1) a vector space, and (2) it is closed under the standard commutation operation. The commutator of matrices then always satisfies the axioms of a Lie bracket, and thus this is sufficient to show that ${\rm Lie}(G)$ is a Lie algebra.

1. Let $X,Y\in{\rm Lie}(G)$. That $\lambda X\in{\rm Lie}(G)$ for all $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ is immediate from the definition. On the other hand, closure under addition, $X+Y\in{\rm Lie}(G)$, follows from the [Lie product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_product_formula) (remembering that $G$ is, by definition, closed):
   $$e^{X+Y} = \lim_{N\to \infty} \left(e^{X/N}e^{Y/N}\right)^N.$$
   In this expression, we know that $X/N,Y/N\in\mathrm{Lie}(G)$, thus $e^{X/N}e^{Y/N}\in G$, and thus we get the limit of a sequence elements of $G\subseteq M(n,\mathbb C)$, which must converge in $G$ due to closedeness.
2. To show that $[X,Y]\equiv XY-YX\in{\rm Lie}(G)$, observe that

   1. For any $g\in G$ and $Y\in{\rm Lie}(G)$, we have ${\rm Ad}(g)(Y)\equiv gYg^{-1}\in{\rm Lie}(G)$, and thus $e^{hX}Y e^{-hX}\in{\rm Lie}(G)$ for any $h\in\mathbb R$ and $X\in\mathrm{Lie}(G)$.

      This result comes from observing how $e^{t (gYg^{-1})}=g e^{tY} g^{-1}\in G$.
   2. Finally,
      $$[X,Y] = \partial_h|_0 e^{hX}Y e^{-hX} \equiv \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{hX}Y e^{-hX}-Y}{h}.$$
      This implies $[X,Y]\in{\rm Lie}(G)$ because $e^{hX}\in G$, and we already proved that ${\rm Lie}(G)$ is a vector space.